# How to find country code from phone number in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to find country code when user enter his/her phone number to login in the app. User just insert his/her phone number and automatically show his/her country code.

Comment: best way to do this thing is insert all country codes in your db and provide a dropdown to user and then you can get it easily.

Comment: But i want to fetch country code automatically when user insert phone number.

Comment: you can not fetch it automatically from user input. because there is no standard. some countries have 1 and some 2 and some 3 to 4 digits country codes. that's why you can not distinguish country code from user input.

Comment: Can I fetch it from api calling by sending phone number as a argument??

Comment: try this.
https://restcountries.eu/#rest-countries-users